# Unusual nans Returned by scipy LinearNDInterpolator

Tags: python-3.x, scipy

I'm trying to interpolate the following data with python (3.8.1) using the aforementioned scipy function ([official documentation here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.LinearNDInterpolator.html#scipy.interpolate.LinearNDInterpolator); [source code here](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/193f160feeeb6256d26ba7d42c627910bc78d4a5/scipy/interpolate/interpnd.pyx#L205)). The official documentation is incredibly sparse, so I'm hopeful that someone else out there will have some experience using the function and may know the source of this issue. Specifically, I run the following four lines of code:

```
    predictor = [[-1.7134013337139833, 0.9582376963057636, -0.21528572746395735], [3.25933089248862, -0.7087236333980123, 0.012808817274351122], [-0.5596739049487544, -1.8723369742231246, 0.03114189522349198], [0.23080764211370225, 1.0639221305852422, -0.602148693975945], [-0.9879484423429669, -0.16678510825693527, 0.5570132252912631], [0.0029439785978213986, -0.10016927713200409, -0.18197412051828055], [0.3530872261969887, 0.6347161018351574, 0.7285361235605389], [-1.122894723267098, 0.22837861478723648, -0.9022469946784363], [-0.02862856314533664, 0.014623415207400122, 3.078346263312741], [-1.3367570531570616, -0.3218239542354167, 0.489878302042675]]
    respose = [0.020235605909933625, 1.4729016163456679e-05, 0.021931080605237303, 0.21271851410989498, 0.26870984350693583, 0.9577608837143238, 0.3470452852299319, 0.11918254249689647, 7.657429164576589e-05, 0.1187813551565562]
    from scipy.interpolate import LinearNDInterpolator
    away = LinearNDInterpolator(predictor, response)
```

Now, if I write `away.__call__([0,0,0])[0]` then python returns `0.8208492283847619`,
which is the desired outcome and is a sensible value based on the given test data. Similarly, `away.__call__([0,0,1])[0]` returns `0.22018657078617598` which is also a sensible value.
However, `away.__call__([0,1,1])[0]` returns `nan`. **What changed?** Does anyone happen to know?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This occurs when `away.__call__(x)` is passed a value `x` which lies outside of the [convex hull](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull) - essentially, when `x` lies outside of the region of interpolation.